# How do I replace a table with text in CSS?

Tags: html, css

So for an assignment of mine I have to use CSS Media Queries to display two webpages depending on the size of the window. I have that done, but for the mobile phone version, I have to replace the tables on the menu page with text, which describes the menu. How do I do this in CSS?

```
@media screen and (min-width: 37.5em) and (max-width: 64em){
header{
  padding-top: 1em;
}

main{
  padding-top: 0.1em;
  padding-bottom: 0.1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  font-size: 90%;
}

h1{
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

nav li{
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFE4C4;
}

nav li::first-line{
  border-top: 1px solid #FFE4C4
}

nav a{
  display: block;
}

#wrapper img{
  background-image: none;
  height: 0;
}

table{
  display: none;
}

#address{
  color: #191970;
  font-size: 92%;
  font-family: Calibri;
  background-image: none;
  border-color: #FFE4C4;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border-style: none;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

table.Coffees:after{
  content: "Our Coffees";
  content: "Our coffees are well-known throughout the region as bold and flavorful. We offer many different types of coffees, one of which is sure to satisfy your taste. Prices start at $2.00 per cup."
}

table.Tea:after{
  content: "Our Teas";
  content: "Our teas are hand-selected from around the world to bring you a wide variety of possibilities. We specialize in flavorful afternoon teas as well as a wide assortmentof exotic teas. Stop in and try a cup! Prices start $2.00 per cup."
}

table.Snacks:after{
  content: "Our Snacks";
  content: "We offer a wide variety of foods ranging from simple snacks to complete inners. Our specialties are organic salads and fresh seafood. Try our fried clam strips and fish strips. The locals swear these are the bestq you'll find anywhere. Prices are seasonal, but always a real deal."
}
```

}

This is what I have for that part of my CSS file. I heard the content property was a way to do it, but I don't see anything.

Thank you in advance!

Upon request, here are the html files for the index page and the menu page respectively:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>The Lighthouse Bistro</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bistro.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<header>
  <h1>The Lighthouse Bistro</h1>
</header>
<nav>
<ul>
<li class="navlist">
  <a href="index.html">Home</a>
</li>
<li class="navlist">
  <a href="menu.html">Our Menu</a>
</li>
<li class="navlist">
  <a href="">Entertainment Schedule</a>
</li>
<li class="navlist">
  <a href="">Reservations</a>
</li>
</ul>
  <div id="address">
    The Lighthouse Bistro
    <br>
    #27 Lighthouse Road
    <br>
    Mackinac City, Michigan 49701
    <br>
    <br>
    888-555-5555
    <br>
  </div>
</nav>
<div role="main">
  <img src="images/oldmackinaclight.jpg" alt="Old Mackinac Light" height="350" width="250">
  <h3>Enjoy Fine Dining and Entertainment at Lighthouse Point</h3>
  <p>The Lighthouse Bistro offers fine dining and entertainment a stones throw from the Old Mackinac Point Lighthouse on the
    Straits of Mackinac. The lighthouse was built in 1892 as a sentinel for vessels entering the Straits of Mackinac. Open year
    round. Yes, even in the winter! Stop in for a mug of one of our specialty coffees after your hike.</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Speciality coffees and teas</li>
    <li>Bagels, Muffins, and Organic Snack</li>
    <li>Clam Strips, Oysters, and Fresh Fish served daily</li>
    <li>Music and Poetry Readings</li>
    <li>Open Mic Night Every Friday starting at 8:00pm</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<footer>
  <br>
  <em>Copyright &copy; 2018 The Lighthouse Bistro</em>
  <br>
  <em><a href="/Email/">ourfirstname@yourlastname.com</a></em>
</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the menu:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>The Lighthouse Bistro</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bistro.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<header>
  <h1>The Lighthouse Bistro</h1>
</header>
<nav>
  <ul>
  <li class="navlist">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="navlist">
    <a href="menu.html">Our Menu</a>
  </li>
  <li class="navlist">
    <a href="">Entertainment Schedule</a>
  </li>
  <li class="navlist">
    <a href="">Reservations</a>
  </li>
  </ul>
    <div id="address">
      The Lighthouse Bistro
      <br>
      #27 Lighthouse Road
      <br>
      Mackinac City, Michigan 49701
      <br>
      <br>
      888-555-5555
      <br>
    </div>
</nav>
<div role="main">
<table class="Coffees">
  <caption>Some of Our Coffees</caption>
  <tr>
    <th id="Coffee">Coffee</th>
    <th id="Desc1">Description</th>
    <th id="Price1">Price</th>
    <th id="Image1">Image</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td headers="Coffee" class="center">Just Java</td>
    <td headers="Desc1">The regular house blend, decaffinated coffee, or the flavor of the day</td>
    <td headers="Price1" class="center">Endless cup $2.00</td>
    <td headers="Image1" class="center"><img src="images/coffee1.jpg" alt="coffee1" width="100" height="75"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="secrow">
    <td headers="Coffee" class="center">Cafe au Lait</td>
    <td headers="Desc1">House blended coffee infused into a smooth steamed milk.</td>
    <td headers="Price1" class="center">Single $2.00, Double $3.00</td>
    <td headers="Image1" class="center"><img src="images/coffee2.jpg" alt="coffee2" width="100" height="75"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td headers="Coffee" class="center">Iced Cappucino</td>
    <td headers="Desc1">Sweetened espresso blended with icy-cold milk and served in a chilled glass</td>
    <td headers="Price1" class="center">Single $4.75, Double $5.75, Wow! $7.75</td>
    <td headers="Image1" class="center"><img src="images/coffee3.jpg" alt="coffee3" width="100" height="75"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="secrow">
    <td headers="Coffee" class="center">Espresso</td>
    <td headers="Desc1">Our house blend espresso - the best!</td>
    <td headers="Price1" class="center">Single $5.00, Double $7.50</td>
    <td headers="Image1" class="center"><img src="images/espresso1.png" alt="espresso" width="100" height="75"></td>
  </tr>
</table class="Teas">
<br>
<table>
  <caption>Some of Our Teas</caption>
  <tr>
    <th id="Tea" scope="col">Tea</th>
    <th id="Desc2" scope="col">Description</th>
    <th id="Price2" scope="col">Price</th>
    <th id="Image2" scope="col">Image</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td headers="Tea" class="center">Breakfast Teas</td>
    <td headers="Desc2">Darjeeling, English Breakfast, Queen Anne, Green tea with lemon</td>
    <td headers="Price2" class="center">Endless cup $2.00</td>
    <td headers="Image2" class="center"><img src="images/tea1.jpg" alt="tea1" width="100" height="75"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="secrow">
    <td headers="Tea" class="center">Afternoon Teas</td>
    <td headers="Desc2">Lemon, Pure Peppermint, Earl Grey, China Oolong</td>
    <td headers="Price2" class="center">Endless cup $3.00</td>
    <td headers="Image2" class="center"><img src="images/tea2.jpg" alt="tea2" width="100" height="75"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td headers="Tea" class="center">Exotic Teas</td>
    <td headers="Desc2">Orange & Cinnammon Spice, Camomile, Honey & Vanilla, Pomegranate & Raspberry</td>
    <td headers="Price2" class="center">Single cup $3.50</td>
    <td headers="Image2" class="center"><img src="images/tea3.jpg" alt="tea3" width="100" height="75"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<table class="Snacks">
  <caption>Snacks</caption>
  <tr>
    <th id="Snack">Snack</th>
    <th id="Desc3">Description</th>
    <th id="Price3">Price</th>
    <th id="Image3">Image</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td headers="Snack" class="center">Bagels and Muffins</td>
    <td headers="Desc3">Bagels, Plain muffins, Blueberry muffins, Chocolate muffins, and much more</td>
    <td headers="Price3" class="center">Small $2.00, Large $3.00</td>
    <td headers="Image3" class="center"><img src="images/muffin1.jpg" alt="muffin1" width="100" height="75"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="secrow">
    <td headers="Snack" class="center">Organic Snacks</td>
    <td headers="Desc3">Organic chips with sea salt, Organic salads</td>
    <td headers="Price3" class="center">Prices vary</td>
    <td headers="Image3" class="center"><img src="images/salad1.jpg" alt="muffin2" width="100" height="75"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td headers="Snack" class="center">Fresh Fish</td>
    <td headers="Desc3">Clam strips, Fried Fish Strips, Fried Oysters, and many other seasonal selections</td>
    <td headers="Price3" class="center">Prices vary by season $5.75-$15.75</td>
    <td headers="Image3" class="center"><img src="images/clamstrips.png" alt="muffin3" width="100" height="75"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<br>
<footer>
  <em>Copyright &copy; 2018 The Lighthouse Bistro</em>
  <br>
  <em><a href="/Email/">yourfirstname@yourlastname.com</a></em>
</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can we see your HTML, too? A [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful.

Comment: Yep! I just edited it so that you can see the code for the html files

Comment: Which one do You want to fix: index or menu page? I don't fully understand the workflow.

Comment: Ah sorry I should have specified. I want the menu to chance. Basically, when the menu page is in its desktop version, you can see the tables. For the mobile version though, the tables will disappear and will be replaced by text. I don't know how to do that